# How to define this class

Tags: java, scala

I have a Scala + Java project.

In the java classes I needed 2 classes that extend from the same class, and their usage is defined in scala.

So I have this class

```
public class BaseUser {

     int id;
     private String name;
     public BaseUser withName(String name){
        this.name = name;
        return this;
     }


}
```

and the extended class

```
   public SpecificUser extends BaseUser {

      //inherit default for now
   }
```

Then in scala I have a definition of a DAO

```
trait BaseUserDao {

    def insertUser(user:BaseUser) : Boolean

}


   class SpecificUserDao  extends UserDao{

       def insertUser(user : SpecificUser) : Boolean = {
            db.insert(user).isDefined
         }
   }
```

But this does not compile, it says that i  have to implement insertUser(user:BaseUser) instead of SpecificUser

How do I define it so that i can create an implementation per user type ?

Comment: insertUser !== inserUser

Comment: @LajosArpad stand corrected, it was a typo

Comment: @LenaBru where is `UserDao` coming from ? Do you mean `BaseUserDao `

Comment: Lena, after fixing the typo how did the behavior change?

Comment: @LenaBru Instead of saying `How to define this class` make the question more informative. So that people understand what this question is about ?

Comment: @LenaBru  You could say, override the method of a trait with specific subtype .. something like this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your implementation to something as shown below. Have a type parameter `T` whose upper bound is `BaseUser`. In the declaration of `SpecificUserDao` just make the `T` `SpecificUser`.

```
trait BaseUserDao[T <: BaseUser] {
  def insertUser(user: T) : Boolean
}

class SpecificUserDao[SpecificUser]  extends BaseUserDao[SpecificUser] {
  override def insertUser(user: SpecificUser): Boolean = ???
}
```

Or you can declare the type `T` inside the trait.

```
trait BaseUserDao {
  type T <: BaseUser
  def insertUser(user: T) : Boolean
}

class SpecificUserDao  extends BaseUserDao {
  override type T = SpecificUser
  override def insertUser(user: SpecificUser): Boolean = ???
}
```

Comment: after defining it like this, I get "someGetter from java is not a member of Nothing"

Comment: Is it possible to do this over some kind of live chat ?

Comment: @LenaBru Consider accepting and upvoting the solution if its helpful

Answer (score -3):

Your constructor should be written like this:

```
public class BaseUser {
    protected int id;
    protected String name;
    public BaseUser(String name){
    this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should I have a constructor in BaseUser ?

Comment: withUser is not a constructor, its a chaining method